# Picker with Menu does not work with Int32 but it works with Int

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, menu, picker

This code does not work, meaning onChange is never called and the variable is not changed when a dropdown option is selected.

```
struct ExamplePicker: View {
    
    @State var val: Int32 = 2
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            
            Menu {
                
                Picker(selection: $val, label: EmptyView()) {
                    
                    Text("Val1").tag(1)
                    Text("Val2").tag(2)
                    Text("Val3").tag(3)
                }                   
            } label: {
                HStack {
                    Text("Value: ")
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Text(String(format: "%d", val))
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: val) { newSelection in
               print(">>> HERE")
           }    
        }
    }
}
```

but if you change val to type **Int** it works perfectly fine.
This looks like a bug to me

EDIT:
Solved - the problem is that in .tag() you need the EXACT same type.
so .tag(1) would be Int not Int32. and thus .tag(Int32(1)) is needed

just to make it more confusing, this works:

```
struct ExamplePicker: View {
    
    @Binding var val: Int64
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            
            Picker(selection: $val, label: EmptyView()) {
                
                Text("Val1").tag(1)
                Text("Val2").tag(2)
                Text("Val3").tag(3)
            }
            .onChange(of: val) { newSelection in
                print(">>> HERE")
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Int64 also works with no problem." Cannot reproduce that. The picker does not change either, if I use `Int64`.

Comment: oh yeah right. but i have a working menu-picker combination using Int64 but there its a @Binding.

Comment: I would need a [mcve] to believe you.

Comment: okay nevermind @Benzy solved it. the type must be exactly the same in .tag().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine when the `tag` values of the `Picker` items have the same type as the state variable. Like this:

```swift
Picker(selection: $val, label: EmptyView()) {
    Text("Val1").tag(Int32(1))
    Text("Val2").tag(Int32(2))
    Text("Val3").tag(Int32(3))
}
```

Comment: oh yeah this looks good. so if the tag is not the exact type of it, it does not change. nice pitfall

Answer (score 1):

When you do `.tag(1)`, the type of `1` is `Int`. `tag` does not know anything about what type of `Binding` you have passed to `selection:` - any `Hashable` thing can go in there:

```
func tag<V>(_ tag: V) -> some View where V : Hashable
```

By type inference, `1` in `tag(1)` is inferred to be `Int`, because I repeat, `tag` doesn't know anything about `selection:`.

So the type of the `selection:` binding is different from the type of the tag. This means that when you select something in the picker, SwiftUI doesn't know what it should change the selection value to. It also doesn't know which option is currently selected, for the same reason.

To make a `Int32` selection work, explicitly say that `1`, `2`, `3` etc are `Int32`s:

```
Text("Val1").tag(Int32(1))
Text("Val2").tag(Int32(2))
Text("Val3").tag(Int32(3))
```

Comment: thanks for the more detailed explanation than @Benzy. Understandable if you know whats happening, but its very hard to spot based on just the syntax.

Comment: funny thing: the type cast is only needed with Menu around the Picker. the picker on its own works with Int64 and Int32 when the tags are given in Int

Comment: @save_jeff Are you sure? I got the message "Picker: the selection "2" is invalid and does not have an associated tag, this will give undefined results" in the log.